# How to use jquery from c# to control

Tags: c#, jquery, class-library

I have pure c# class library which generating div on the fly. I want to apply the menu like effect to the div which dynamically generated on mouse over of on of html generic button control. I have .js file with me. i know which function has to apply. but how to apply i docn't know. can you guys help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just apply the method to the div and make the js available in the client side then that should be it. Basically you have to make sure your js is there on all the requests that uses the class-library generated divs. If that is Asp.net web pages you can put the .js to the master page.

Comment: ok, so is there any way to make available the .js file at client side? can i register the .js file from my class library classess to client ?

Comment: not perticularly, i wanted to use c# class library. but as i tried to call the jquery function form the .js file in asp.net code application behind, but getting error : "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected"